# How we can connect the signals and slot with different arguments?

Tags: qt, qt4

In Qt, signals and slots require matching argument types:

> QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments QLabel::linkActivated(QString) --> Button::call(int)

How can I implement a combination like this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A simple method is to have an intermediate slot that calls the slot that you want. e.g.

```
connect(src, SIGNAL(linkActivated(QString)), this, SLOT(receiveLink(QString)));
```

and then

```
void receiveLink(QString blah)
{
  int response = someFunction(blah);
  mybutton->call(response);
}
```

You have to define some way to interpret the string into an int.

Answer (score 41):

From the [signals slots documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html):

> The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving
>   slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it
>   receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)

This means that a signal of the form

`signal(int, int, QString`)

can only be connected with slots with the following signatures

```
slot1(int, int, QString)
slot2(int, int)
slot3(int)
slot4()
```

As koan suggests the best approach is to use another slot with a QString argument and then call the slot you actually want.

Answer (score 6):

Default values for slot parameters helps very well. This allow to connect signals with different signatures to slot (vice versa to @pnezis answer):

```
private slots:
  void slot( int x = 10, int y = 20, QString text = QString() );
```

may be connected to different signals:

```
signal1(int, int, QString)
signal2(int, int)
signal3(int)
signal4()
```

---

Also Qt 4.8 suggest useful [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) class:

> This class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal.

But only for one parameter:

```
QSignalMapper* mapper = new QSignalMapper(this) ;

connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), mapper, SLOT(map())) ;
mapper->setMapping(action, "param value") ;

connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(const QString &)),
  this, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString &)));
```

Answer (score 1):

a more modern solution would be using [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qoverload-proxy.html)

```
struct Foo {
        void overloadedFunction(int, const QString &);
        void overloadedFunction(int, const QString &) const;
    };
    ... qConstOverload<int, const QString &>(&Foo::overloadedFunction)
    ... qNonConstOverload<int, const QString &>(&Foo::overloadedFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer, if you don't want to write an intermediate slot, you can use the lambda expressions (of course with C++11 support) to invoke the method. However, the connector class must know the parameter types used in those particular signals and slots.

To give an example, assuming that you're trying to connect a signal with a parameter type of `QString` to a slot with a parameter type of `char`, you can do it like this;

```
class SignalClass{
signals:
    void testSignal(QString tString);
};

class SlotClass{
public slots:
    void testSlot(char tChar);
};

class ConnectorClass{
public:
    void connectSignalAndSlot () {
        SignalClass tSigClass;
        SlotClass tSlotClass;
        connect(&tSigClass, &SignalClass::testSignal,
                [=](QString tString) { this->metaObject()->invokeMethod(tSlotClass,"testSlot", Q_ARG(char, tString.at(0).toLatin1())) }
        );
    }
}
```

Kinda ugly stuff, but does the job.

- No coupled classes
- No intermediate connector functions