# Qt Connect signals with different arguments

Tags: c++, qt, arguments, signals-slots

I have a simple question guys, reading the thread about [connecting signals with slots with fewer arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926978/thread-how-we-can-connect-the-signals-and-slot-with-different-arguments), and of course, the Qt documentation.

However, I do not need to connect signals with slots. I actually want to connect signals with *signals with fewer arguments*.

The documentation is very clear about slots, but what about signals?

Is that considered safe?

Thanks & Cheers!

Comment: Did you try? I think it should work: `connect(SIGNAL(foo(int, int)), SIGNAL(goo(int)));`

Comment: Yes, it works, I've tried. But also it works if you set icons on widgets in a separate thread, but it is not guaranteed to always work. I was looking for an official doc...

Comment: How about SLOT has more argument than SIGNAL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. The receiving signal may have a shorter signature than the emitting signal. because it can ignore extra arguments. You can connect a signal like:

```
signal(int, int, int)
```

TO SIGNAL with the following signatures:

```
signal1(int, int, int)
signal2(int, int)
signal3(int)
signal4()
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why the documentation mentions only slots. Do you think they just forgot to mention signals?

Comment: Documentation tolds that there is no difference in connection. You may connect signals to signals in same way as signals to slots.