# A slot connected to QCombox::currentIndexChanged signal does not get triggered

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qcombobox, qt-signals

Qt version: 5.6.

```cpp
connect(ui.m_projectList, SIGNAL(currentlndexChanged(const QString&)), this, SLOT(OnProjectListChange(const QString&)));
```

```cpp
void RunTestUI::OnProjectListChange(const QString& _p)
{
    QString project = ui.m_projectList->currentText();
    std::wstring clientPath = GetRunClientPath();
    std::wstring projectConfigPath = FilePath::Combine(clientPath, L"ServerConfig-" + project.toStdWString() + L".json");
    std::wstring destConfigPath = FilePath::Combine(clientPath, L"ServerConfig.json");
    FileUtility::CopyFileW(projectConfigPath, destConfigPath);
}
```

`ui.m_projectList` is a QComboBox, `OnProjectListChange` is the slot, but it does not get triggered when `m_projectList` is changed.

I tried the following code, but still failed:

```cpp
connect(ui.m_projectList, SIGNAL(currentlndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(OnProjectListChange()));
```

Comment: You don't have a slot `OnProjectListChange()` - only one taking a QString

Comment: Avoid lehacy `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. Qt Creator has refactoring in context menu to convert to current syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How we can connect the signals and slot with different arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926978/how-we-can-connect-the-signals-and-slot-with-different-arguments)

Comment: Is that a small L instead of an I in SIGNAL(currentlndexChanged(int))

Comment: @JürgenLutz Yes it is; it is visible when displayed in code font `currentlndexChanged` vs `currentIndexChanged`. Besides, Qt 5.6 has long exceeded its support period (ended in March 2019), as were all the other versions of Qt5, including the last one: Qt 5.15 LTS (unless you are a paying licensee, but that will not last for much longer now). Upgrade to Qt6.